# "where in" MySQL query in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, where-clause

I need to make MySQL query using "WHERE IN".
This is my query:

```
var myQuery = 'SELECT uid FROM ' +tableName+ ' where Gender IN (' + Info.Gender.join() + ')';
```

If i print `Info.Gender` it will be ['Male', 'Female'], as a string.
but when the query is done it says

```
SELECT uid FROM appUsers where Gender IN (Male, Female)
```

But should be:

```
SELECT uid FROM appUsers where Gender IN ('Male', 'Female')
```

That means it takes the Female not as a string.

Any ideas?

Comment: `' where Gender IN (\'' + Info.Gender.join("', '") + \'')';`

Comment: When you're generating SQL in javascript, it's smart to always use double quotes, so you can be sure that any single quotes will be part of the SQL and not of the javascript.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use [query escaping](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values) (provided that you're using `node-mysql`):

```
var myQuery = 'SELECT uid FROM ?? where Gender IN (?)';
connection.query(myQuery, [ tableName, Info.Gender ], ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need single quotes in your query:

```
var myQuery = "SELECT uid FROM " +tableName+ " where Gender IN ('" + Info.Gender.join("','") + "')";
```

Comment: For future visitors, use escaping instead of this proposed answer.

Comment: will this escape user input? it seems dangerous